# Force use Incompatible Cordova Plugins with Capacitor

Tags: ios, xcode, cordova, ionic3, capacitor

Is it possible to force the use of "[Known incompatible plugins](https://capacitorjs.com/docs/cordova/known-incompatible-plugins)" on my dual-platform Ionic capacitor app? **The reasons:**

1. The ionic source was developed for both Android & iOS and initially tested only on Android.
2. The capacitor Splash-Screen and Status-Bar plugins hold little value and fail to do all the things I need. For example: setting the background-color of the status bar on iOS through use of a hex-string: [issue](https://github.com/ionic-team/capacitor/issues/2101).

**The issue:** When bringing over changes to XCode, one of the commands that runs is `pod install` coming from `npx cap sync`, resulting in the exclusion of any incompatible plugins from being downloaded for the iOS source.

**The question:** Is there a by-the-book/non-destructive way of using conflicting cordova plugins on capacitor? (Specifically Splash-Screen & Status-Bar)

**The comment:** I know Ionic-Enterprise plugins would likely solve my issue, I do not have it.

Thank you for taking the time!

Comment: For any further viewers, I resolved the issue by switching to capacitor plugins after days of searching for a way of doing what I asked above.